# International shipping not working after upgrade

Tags: magento-1.9, shipping, upgrade, shipping-methods, ce-1.9.2.4

We had a company upgrade our website from Magento 1.7.0.2 to Magento version 1.9.2.4.

For some reason after the upgrade our international shipping method does not show on the checkout page.

Does anyone have any idea what could be causing the problem?

Comment: I just wrote this to the ones that did the upgrade. I know you are working on the International Shipping. I noticed that currently the USPS shipping is not showing up at all. 

I just checked the last 200 orders and I noticed that since June 16 the only orders that were USPS shipping were either edited in the admin panel, or Flat-Rate (which is not really USPS)

USPS is the only carrier we use for international shipping. That being so, it could be that the international shipping is an issue with USPS not international shipping

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that the USPS API credentials did not work in the upgraded magento site. I've gotten new API credentials and USPS works, as I said in the comment, the issue was USPS wasn't working and USPS is what we use for international shipping